# Need help in Removing Square braces and apply that as a condition in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help in SQL Server. My input comes from the UI, it comes as `[Amazon, Kroger, Walmart]` when multiple elements are selected.

Now the value is passed to SQL Server and the table data should be filtered and send the data back to the API.

PFB for my table data:

[image]

I tried parsing the value which is coming from UI and replace the square brackets and apply the where clause, it's not working:

```
select Account, Channel 
from GetMasterData 
where Account in ((select '''' + REPLACE((select REPLACE(REPLACE('[Amazon,Kroger,Walmart]', '[', ''),']', '') as value),  ',', ''',''')+'''' as value))
```

Comment: [`TRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the brackets (`[]`) from the string and then [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) them?

Comment: Your attempt returns a *scalar* value, in this case the `varchar` value `'''Amazon'',''Kroger'',''Walmart'''` (quotes are escaped); that is *not* the same as a *list* of the `varchar` *values* `'Amazon'`, `'Kroger'`, and `'Walmart'`. Your query effectively have `WHERE Account = '''Amazon'',''Kroger'',''Walmart'''` and hopefully you can see why that doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest your UI pass the list as a proper json array with the strings enclosed in double-quotes (e.g. `["Amazon","Kroger","Walmart"]`). That will allow you to use T-SQL `OPENJSON`: `WHERE Account IN (SELECT value FROM OPENJSON('["Amazon","Kroger","Walmart"]'));`. Of course, your actual query should be parameterized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. <s>But sql injection is possible.</s>

```
select Account, Channel 
from GetMasterData 
where Account in (select [value] from STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE('[Amazon,Kroger,Walmart]', '[', ''),']', ''), ','))
```

Comment: There is no SQL injection avenue here.

Comment: Thanks, STRING_SPLIT function is working